# Troubleshooting electrical scooter lack of power and battery runs low too fast

Tags: dc-motor

This is my first post here so I hope I'm doing it right :-)

**The problem**

My mother has a 3 year old electrical scooter (from April 2019). After a couple of years the battery started to run low rather quickly and she couldn't drive around on her usual trips. So in August 2021 she bought and installed a replacement battery.

After replacing the battery the situation improved to some extent but it could still only drive half the distance compared to when the scooter was new. Shortly after she also started to notice lack of power when driving uphill and the battery quickly runs low again.

So now I am trying to see if I can figure out the problem. I have checked to see that the wheels spins freely with no resistance and I believe it's an electrical, rather than mechanical, issue.  I have some basic understanding of electricity but I would very much appreciate some inputs from people with more experience/knowledge.

**A bit of info on the system:**

- The battery is a 24v system (2 times 12v batteries with 22ah each of the lead-acid type)
- The label on the motor states that it is a 24v DC motor with a rated
  power of 180W with a "No-Load amp" on up to 3.0A (see picture below)
- The system seems to consist of 3 main parts: the battery connects to an electronic control unit which in turn connects to the motor itself. The electronic control unit is responsible for throttle control.
- In case you need it, the scooter is this one: https://www.blimo.dk/Blimo_T-35 (Danish website)

[image: Motor]

**My tests and measurements**

I have made some voltage and amperage measurements while trying to put the motor into different load conditions. First of all, a quick description of how I measured: the voltage measurements were made with a multimeter with piercing probes directly to the positive and negative wire coming out of the battery box (to rule out voltage drops from bad connections etc). The amperage was measured simultaneously with another multimeter using an amp clamp around the positive battery wire (the wire that runs from the battery to the electronic control unit). See following picture.

[image: Test setup]

Here is the various test conditions and resulting measurements (with a fully charged battery):

- Wheels raised in the air (no load condition) with full throttle: 25,7V and 3,4A
- Me sitting on the scooter driving into a wall to prevent the wheels from turning with full throttle (stall / full load condition): 20,9V and 88A (I only did this for a couple of seconds to avoid burning the motor)
- Me driving around in my gravel driveway at low speeds with various throttle positions to observe the relationship between amp draw and battery voltage resulting in these measurements (approximate values as reading two multimeters simultaneously was not so easy) :
- - 24,3V and 12A
- - 23,8V and 22A
- - 22,0V and 30A

**My thoughts and conclusions**

I don't have experience with similar systems so I got nothing to compare to - but it looks to me that the battery voltage drops too low and hence I'm suspecting if the battery is the culprit? (even though it was replaced 7 months ago).

However, I'm also a bit puzzled about the power rating on the motor saying 180W while the measurements above are resulting in much higher wattage.

Any help will be much appreciated and I will gladly carry out more tests if needed! :-)

Comment: Just a quick "sanity-check" - your mom did replace *both* 12V batteries in 2021 and not just one of them didn't she?

Comment: Your no-load current draw seems to be close to spec, so it's probably not that.  Did the replacement batteries come from the same company?  It's not unusual for batteries to wear out after a couple of years of heavy use.  My suspicions -- which you'd need to check on -- are (1) bad replacement batteries, (2) the charger has gone bad, or the wiring to it, (3) you have a mechanical fault (bad bearings?) that cause more current draw under load.  Check that your battery voltage under charge is correct for the battery chemistry (i.e., 2.3V/cell for lead-acid).

Comment: And edit your question with the battery chemistry -- is it lead-acid, LiPo, LiFe, or what?

Comment: And did you buy cheap car batteries or the traction rated batteries?

Comment: Right now the most likely explanation is that the replacement batteries are not as good as the original batteries. If you want to look at the motor, it might be a good idea to take it out and rotate the shaft by hand to check that it rotates smoothly and doesn't have too much friction. If it does, you can try either re-lubricating it or replacing it. I assume that the motor has a built-in reduction gear. That gear could be going bad also and causing lots of frictional loss.

Comment: Hi All. Thanks for the feedback so far. To answer the questions: Yes _both_ batteries was replaced. The batteries are of the lead-acid type. With the wheels up off the ground, I have rotated them to see if both spins freely and everything feels fine as far as I can tell (no resistance or play).

Comment: As for what types the replacement batteries was, they were bought from the same company with the same specs (2 x 12v 22ah) which matches the original - but whether they are truly the same as the originals I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The 180 watt motor rating is likely the mechanical output power rating. That would conform to international standards for  motor rating markings. However other markings on the label do not conform to standards, lack of full load current marking and other details, so interpreting the markings is uncertain. A motor that size is not going to be very efficient. There must be a speed reduction gear built into the motor. That will not be very efficient. Some of the problem may be lack of gear lubrication. The electronic controller will have losses, but it probably quite efficient compared to the motor.

If the batteries were replaced with automotive batteries rather than "deep-discharge" or "marine" batteries that is likely most of the problem. Even if the proper type of battery was selected, battery quality could be an issue.

Comment: Some cheap batteries sold on ebay and Aliex are counterfeit knockoffs and they do not know or say who made them. Did the scooter rider gain a lot of weight like many of them do?